# Pooling coefficients from Ridge Regression in R (Multiple imputation)

Tags: r

I am fitting a ridge regression model on a multiply imputed dataset (10 imputations with mice package). I want to display the pooled regression coefficients from the model.

The model fitting is done in a loop and the models are saved in a list `mods3`

```
mods3 <- vector(mode="list", length=10)

for (i in 1:10)
{
#Prepare data
  x_train_std_imp<- x_train_std[x_train_std$.imp==i,]
  X <- as.matrix(x_train_std_imp[,-1])
  y_train_std_imp<- y_train_std[y_train_std$.imp==i,]
  Y <- as.matrix(y_train_std_imp[,-1])
#Fit model
  cv_train_std <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, nfolds=10, type.measure="deviance", alpha=0, family="binomial")
  lambda <- cv_train_std$lambda.min
  mods3[[i]] <- glmnet(X, Y, family="binomial", lambda=lambda, alpha=0)
  pred <- predict(mods3[[i]],lambda, type="response",newx= X)
  i=i+1
}
```

However, if I try to pool the data with the `pool()` function from the `mice` package, I get the following error:

```
pooled<-pool(mods3)
Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `ubar`.
ℹ `ubar = mean(.data$std.error^2)`.
x Column `std.error` not found in `.data`
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: term = (Intercept).
Backtrace:
```

I understand that the `pool()` function is not made for `glmnet` models, but is there some workaround? I would like to use the `plot_summs()` function on the pooled results.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Generally, you can pool any statistic for which you have a point estimate and a variance estimate using `pool.scalar()`. So if you can extract the estimates and standard errors (square them for variance) of interest from your models, pass them on to pool.scalar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I figured that the standard errors of ridge regression parameter estimates should not be pooled across models. The reason is the penalization of the ridge regression model. Small standard errors can be due to penalization of the coefficient, pooling across models where possibly parameters are penalized differently is not sensible in this case.